# combine ansible async with fio/iperf

Tags: ansible, subprocess, performance-testing

working with anible async I'm trying to run fio and iperf on multipls machines at the same time.
the usage is python subprocess that executes both playbooks.

the problem is that the fio playbook doesn't recognize that the fio command actually finished running (thus failing the playbook on timeout) the actual task from the playbook is below:

```
  - name: Execute the fio tests according to vm roles
    shell: "fio --output-format=json --output out_{{ vnf_name }}_{{inventory_hostname}}.json --section {{ 
            vm_role }} {{ vnf_name }}.fio"
    args:
     chdir: "{{ fio_dir }}"
    become: true
    async: '{{final_time}}'
    poll: 0
    register: fio_status

 - name: poll fio status
   async_status:
     jid: "{{ fio_status.ansible_job_id }}"
   register: fio_job_result
   until: fio_job_result.finished
   retries: 30
   delay: "{{((final_time| int) / 30) | int}}"
```

ansible config:

```
[defaults]
forks = 200
host_key_checking = False
log_path = /var/log/ansible.log
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the task has actually finished running on the target before the `final_time` seconds period has elapsed ? If ansible sees it still running, I tend to think that it is actually the case.

Comment: well, going to the machine in question I see the actuall process is not running anymore, I'll check again though to make sure trice as. just to note, when I see in ansible the list of all machines (and tasks results) at the end it means that they finished right? if so, it looks like ansible as well thought it was already finished.

Comment: Did you know that on Linux [fio has a client/server mode](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#client-server)?

Comment: yes, I execute pairs, one in each is a client and the other a server.

Answer (score 0):

Set the fio command to time_based and runtime.

- --time_based
- --runtime=120

  sudo fio --filename=device name --direct=1 --rw=randread --bs=4k --ioengine=libaio --iodepth=256 --runtime=120 --numjobs=4 --time_based --group_reporting --name=iops-test-job --eta-newline=1 --readonly

For more information, refer to https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#time-related-parameters